# Unmet dependencies when trying to remove libnvidia-ifr1-390

Tags: nvidia, package-management, dependencies

```
zags@zags:~$ sudo apt-get remove libnvidia-ifr1-390
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
zags@zags:~$
```

Output of `sudo apt-get install -f` :

```
libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f`? If yes, please paste output in question body

Comment: @Kulfy yes sir , now you can see the output after running that command

Comment: i dont know what to do , and i have no idea what am doing , please guide

Comment: libnvidia-ifr1-390 is a dependency of your installed graphics driver, nvidia-driver-390, so you **can't remove** it or you won't have any proprietary graphics driver. The 2nd error when after running `sudo apt-get install -f` may be caused because the system is trying to both update and remove the same packages at the same time, so the system does nothing and returns an error message.

Comment: @karel okay sir , got you
now what should i do? am getting that red error icon beside my wifi and volume icon which says some unmet dependencies , how to remove that?

Comment: There are two possible approaches to solving this problem, which suggests to me that at least two people should post answers. The first approach is if you're satisfied with your currently installed proprietary graphics driver, wait for 2 days and maybe this problem will go away by itself. The second approach is to try to resolve the unmet dependencies right away. I recommend that you wait for answers to be posted and then decide what to do.

Answer (score 5):

Same issue. Solved with this:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2388026&page=3&p=13761809#post13761809

```
for FILE in $(dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-340 | awk '{print $3}'); do sudo dpkg-divert --remove $FILE; done
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade
```