# Can't update Ubuntu. Tried (and failed) to install vulkan and crippled myself in the process

Tags: nvidia, updates, gpu

It turns out that my GTX geForce 570 doesn't support vulkan... but I had been meddling with my drivers a lot before figuring that out.

As it stands, my computer's screen resolution is set wrong, I can't run openGL anymore, and my GPU isn't listed under "Settings" > "About" > "Graphics"

Buuuut...

If I look at the active driver under "Software & Updates" > "Additional Drivers", not only is 390 listed and selected, but it won't let me choose any other driver (if I try choosing Nouveau or 340, when I "apply changes" it pauses and then 390 becomes active once again. Rebooting doesn't help). This is still the case, even if I run

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

And finally, I can't receive updates. The auto-updates have a number of items queued up, but if I try to update any of them, I get an error window which reads:

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libnvidia-ifr1-390: Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not installed
libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386: Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not installed
nvidia-driver-390: Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not installed
                   Depends: nvidia-dkms-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-compute-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-decode-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-encode-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: nvidia-utils-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
                   Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-390 (= 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but 390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 is installed
```

I thought I had purged 390?
Please help!

EDIT:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 libllvm8 libllvm8:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/29.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 147 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 209301 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get install -f` and then post the output if you have problems. Thanks!

Comment: Also,  do you want the correct nvidia driver installed or do you want to use nouveau instead? I ask this because the system may try to re-install 390 and also there is a command to run that will automatically install the correct version for your chipset.

Comment: I want to use NVIDIA- it was working a few days ago. The purge was an attempt at a clean re-install.

Running that command gives too much output to fit here, but it ends with:
`Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Thanks. You can click on "edit" to edit your question and you can post the output in your question.

Comment: Gotcha. Full output posted above under 'EDIT. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Here is an answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1084470/167115 When you are done with that, you can run the following command to make sure the correct driver is installed or to reinstall the correct driver: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: If 340 is not the correct driver, you may want to get rid of the 340 driver. It looks like 390 is the correct driver for the geForce GTX 570 according to the nvidia website.

Comment: Also, did you see this question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090945/ubuntu-18-04-vulkan-stopped-working-nvidia-drivers-proprietary

Comment: I ran the code on that first link, and rebooted. Everything is back to normal.
Thank you so much- I've been grinding at this for two days now- I seriously appreciate it.

I'm not sure I understand the issue though- one driver was adding some files while another was removing them?

Comment: Awesome! I will vote this as a duplicate. Yeah, it looks like there were some conflicting files. I try to only have one version installed and using the autoinstall command helps to have the system decide which one is recommended.